# Mongodb: How to configure monogdb so that it requires password while making a connection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongodb with Node.js and I make my connection as follows:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017,
{ native_parser: true }
));
mongoClient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
    db = mongoclient.db('mydb');
});
```

As it is clear It requires no password, My concern is that how to set up password with mongodb and when I try to make connection then It should require password. How to do it?

Comment: Yes I had the same problem now it is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the resource 
http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongodb-add-users-and-authenticate.html 
mongod --auth --setParameter enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0 the last option is to disable localhost bypass..

Answer (score 1):

You need to start mongod with the --auth option after setting up the user.

From the MongoDB Site: Run the database (mongod process) with the --auth option to enable security. You must either have added a user to the admin db before starting the server with --auth, or add the first user from the localhost interface.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication